# In Final Fantasy XVI, who was responsible for this event, Clive or the ifrit?

Tags: video-games, final-fantasy

From [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/FinalFantasyXVI):

> During the attack something unprecedented occurs: a monstrous entity emerges from within the castle walls, Ifrit, a *second* Eikon of Fire; something which should be impossible to exist. When the flames settle, the only survivor is Clive, who is seized by the Empire and enslaved as a Bearer to fight in their military. 13 years after the fall of Rosaria, Clive takes an opportunity to escape the Empire and sets off on a Roaring Rampage of Revenge, intent on tracking down the cloaked figure he believes to be Ifrit's Dominant and killing them to claim vengeance for Joshua.

Did Clive kill Joshua or it was the ifrit?
Why does Clive say “I’ll fucking kill you” at the end of the fight?

Comment: What game is that for?

Comment: I removed what I believe to be a major spoiler of FFXVI, which is still a very recent game, from the title